# React - Delete without click (onClick)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use glyphicon with delete function as below:

```
<i className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onClick={this.deleteBook(book._id)}></i>
```

I think it should delete when click but when the page render, all contents are deleted without clicking.

The following is all part of code:

```
<div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <ul className="book-list">
                            {this.state.pageOfItems.map(book => (
                                <li key={book._id} className="book-list__item">
                                    <div className="book thumbnail">
                                        <div className="caption">
                                            <h3 onClick={() => this.props.history.push(`${this.props.match.url}/view/${book._id}`)}>{book.title}</h3>
                                            <h4>{book.bookdate}</h4>
                                            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onClick={this.deleteBook(book._id)}></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, inside JSX `{...}` all JS expression gets executed. So when you write, `onClick={this.deleteBook(book._id)}`, you are executing the function with this `()`, as you wrote `this.deleteBook(book._id)`. Let's wrap it inside the **Arrow fucntion** as

```
onClick={() => this.deleteBook(book._id)}
```

With this `onClick` props, you attached a function object as an event handler. So when the click will happen this handler function will be called internally. Don't execute the event handler by yourself, let them called by the specific events you attached to.

Answer (score 1):

Either do this

```
onClick={() => this.deleteBook(book._id)}
```

Or **second approach**

```
onClick={this.deleteBook(book._id)}
```

Then where you define your function do this

```
this.deleteBook = id => () => {}
```

Comment: The second approach would call the function on render itself

Comment: No it will not this `this.deleteBook = id => () => {}` is same as this approach `() => this.deleteBook(book._id)`

Comment: @Adeel Imran, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Please using the onClick function as below:

```
onClick={() => this.deleteBook.bind(this, book._id)}
```

So for receiving book._id argument value after clicking on the element, use the following model:

```
deleteBook(id, event) {// todo someting}
```